# Adding one column with multiple columns excluding NAN values in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below:

```
    FIRST  SECOND  SCORE       S1       S2       S3       S4       S5       S6       S7  S8
0       1       1  38147      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
1       2       1    567  38147.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
2       3       1      0    567.0  38147.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
3       4       1      0      0.0    567.0  38147.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
4       5       1      0      0.0      0.0    567.0  38147.0      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
5       6       1      0      0.0      0.0      0.0    567.0  38147.0      NaN      NaN NaN
6       7       1      0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0    567.0  38147.0      NaN NaN
7       8       1    586      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0    567.0  38147.0 NaN
8       1       2   3099      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
9       2       2  30460   3099.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
10      3       2   2372  30460.0   3099.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
11      4       2      0   2372.0  30460.0   3099.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
12      5       2      0      0.0   2372.0  30460.0   3099.0      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
13      6       2      0      0.0      0.0   2372.0  30460.0   3099.0      NaN      NaN NaN
14      7       2      0      0.0      0.0      0.0   2372.0  30460.0   3099.0      NaN NaN
15      8       2    267      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0   2372.0  30460.0   3099.0 NaN
```

I want to add the '**SCORE**' column with all the columns starting with '**S and a number**' (S1, S2, S3...) such that only the S columns having values gets added up where as the 'NAN' remain as 'NAN'.

The number of postfix after S is already known by a variable '**repeat = 8**' which might help in getting the number of columns with S

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
    FIRST  SECOND  SCORE       S1       S2       S3       S4       S5       S6       S7  S8
0       1       1  38147      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
1       2       1    567  38714.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
2       3       1      0    567.0  38147.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
3       4       1      0      0.0    567.0  38147.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
4       5       1      0      0.0      0.0    567.0  38147.0      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
5       6       1      0      0.0      0.0      0.0    567.0  38147.0      NaN      NaN NaN
6       7       1      0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0    567.0  38147.0      NaN NaN
7       8       1    586    586.0    586.0    586.0    586.0    586.0   1153.0  38733.0 NaN
8       1       2   3099      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
9       2       2  30460  33559.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
10      3       2   2372  30460.0   5471.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
11      4       2      0   2372.0  32832.0   3099.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
12      5       2      0      0.0   2372.0  30460.0   3099.0      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
13      6       2      0      0.0      0.0   2372.0  30460.0   3099.0      NaN      NaN NaN
14      7       2      0      0.0      0.0      0.0   2372.0  30460.0   3099.0      NaN NaN
15      8       2    267    267.0    267.0    267.0    267.0   2639.0  30727.0   3366.0 NaN
```

Is there a way to efficiently do it without using for loop so that it works on a big data?

Example input data:

```
import pandas as pd

data_ex = [
    [1,1,38147,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [2,1,567,38147, np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [3,1,0,567,38147, np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [4,1,0,0,567,38147, np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [5,1,0,0,0,567,38147, np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [6,1,0,0,0,0,567,38147, np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [7,1,0,0,0,0,0,567,38147, np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [8,1,586,0,0,0,0,0,567,38147, np.NaN],
    [1,2,3099,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [2,2,30460,3099,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [3,2,2372,30460,3099,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [4,2,0,2372,30460,3099,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN ],
    [5,2,0,0,2372,30460,3099,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,],
    [6,2,0,0,0,2372,30460,3099,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [7,2,0,0,0,0,2372,30460,3099,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [8,2,267,0,0,0,0,2372,30460,3099,np.NaN],
       
]

#dataframe
test_data = pd.DataFrame(data_ex, columns = ['FIRST', 'SECOND', 'SCORE', 'S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7', 'S8'])
```

Equivalent R code:

```
 output<- test_data [, map(.SD, .f = function(.){. + SCORE}),.SDcols = paste0('S',seq(1:repeat))]
```

Comment: Does [Pandas sum of two columns - dealing with nan-values correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61636049/pandas-sum-of-two-columns-dealing-with-nan-values-correctly) answer your question?

Comment: Why isn't the score added to properly to S1 in row 1 and 10 in your desired output?

Comment: @ScootCork thanks for pointing it out. Updated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use [`DataFrame.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) aligned on `axis=0` with the S cols and the `SCORE` column:

```
# Get List of S Cols
cols = test_data.columns[test_data.columns.str.match(r'S\d+')]
# Add S cols to SCORE and update
test_data[cols] = test_data[cols].add(test_data['SCORE'], axis=0)
```

*We don't need to worry about `NaN` becoming any other number since `NaN` + any number is `NaN`

`cols`:

```
Index(['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7', 'S8'], dtype='object')
```

`test_data`:

```
    FIRST  SECOND  SCORE       S1       S2       S3       S4       S5       S6       S7  S8
0       1       1  38147      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
1       2       1    567  38714.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
2       3       1      0    567.0  38147.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
3       4       1      0      0.0    567.0  38147.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
4       5       1      0      0.0      0.0    567.0  38147.0      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
5       6       1      0      0.0      0.0      0.0    567.0  38147.0      NaN      NaN NaN
6       7       1      0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0    567.0  38147.0      NaN NaN
7       8       1    586    586.0    586.0    586.0    586.0    586.0   1153.0  38733.0 NaN
8       1       2   3099      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
9       2       2  30460  33559.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
10      3       2   2372  32832.0   5471.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
11      4       2      0   2372.0  30460.0   3099.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
12      5       2      0      0.0   2372.0  30460.0   3099.0      NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
13      6       2      0      0.0      0.0   2372.0  30460.0   3099.0      NaN      NaN NaN
14      7       2      0      0.0      0.0      0.0   2372.0  30460.0   3099.0      NaN NaN
15      8       2    267    267.0    267.0    267.0    267.0   2639.0  30727.0   3366.0 NaN
```

Comment: `cols = df.filter(regex=r'S\d+')` :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

data_ex = [
    [1,1,38147,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [2,1,567,38147, np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [3,1,0,567,38147, np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [4,1,0,0,567,38147, np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [5,1,0,0,0,567,38147, np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [6,1,0,0,0,0,567,38147, np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [7,1,0,0,0,0,0,567,38147, np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [8,1,586,0,0,0,0,0,567,38147, np.NaN],
    [1,2,3099,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [2,2,30460,3099,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [3,2,2372,30460,3099,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [4,2,0,2372,30460,3099,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN ],
    [5,2,0,0,2372,30460,3099,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,],
    [6,2,0,0,0,2372,30460,3099,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [7,2,0,0,0,0,2372,30460,3099,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [8,2,267,0,0,0,0,2372,30460,3099,np.NaN],
       
]

#dataframe
test_data = pd.DataFrame(data_ex, columns = ['FIRST', 'SECOND', 'SCORE', 'S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7', 'S8'])
repeat = 8

s_columns = ['S{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,repeat+1)]

#Melt into long form
melted_test_data = test_data.melt(
    id_vars = ['FIRST','SECOND','SCORE'],
    value_vars = s_columns,
    var_name = 'S',
    value_name = 'value',
)

#Add the SCORE to the values
melted_test_data['value'] += melted_test_data['SCORE']

#Pivot back to wide form
test_data = melted_test_data.pivot(
    index=['FIRST','SECOND','SCORE'],
    columns = 'S',
    values = 'value',
).reset_index()

test_data.columns.name = ''

test_data
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Solution:

```
test_data.filter(regex='^S\d{1}', axis=1).add(test_data['SCORE'], axis=0)
```

Output:

```
    S1       S2     S3       S4     S5      S6      S7      S8
0   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   38714.0 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   567.0   38147.0 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
3   0.0     567.0   38147.0 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
4   0.0     0.0     567.0   38147.0 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
5   0.0     0.0     0.0     567.0   38147.0 NaN     NaN     NaN
6   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     567.0   38147.0 NaN     NaN
7   586.0   586.0   586.0   586.0   586.0   1153.0  38733.0 NaN
8   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
9   33559.0 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
10  32832.0 5471.0  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
11  2372.0  30460.0 3099.0  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
12  0.0     2372.0  30460.0 3099.0  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
13  0.0     0.0     2372.0  30460.0 3099.0  NaN     NaN     NaN
14  0.0     0.0     0.0     2372.0  30460.0 3099.0  NaN     NaN
15  267.0   267.0   267.0   267.0   2639.0  30727.0 3366.0  NaN
```