# Code returning NaN, but same line of code worked for similar situations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been copy/pasting this line of code to sum instances of a certain text occuring, and it was working up until I hit the last two columns. Figured I would reach out to you good people and see what the problem might be. Thx.

[Excel file im getting data from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0ocF.png)

```
tie_win_count = df['TIE'].str.contains('doneontie', flags=re.I).values.sum()
```

For some reason, this code doesn't work on this column, but has worked on other columns that have similar values. I am sure, like most problems, it is obvious to everyone but me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: "NA" is probably being parsed to `NaN`. `.str.contains` will propagate those `NaN`s. `.values.sum` will return `NaN` if any of the values in the input are `NaN`.

Comment: If you use `tie_win_count = df['TIE'].str.contains('doneontie', flags=re.I).sum()` it will give the count and ignore NaNs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of ways to handle accidental NaN.

1. Replace them with zeroes before calling the sum:

> df['TIE'].str.contains('doneontie', flags=re.I).fillna(0).values.sum()

2. Alternatively, switch to numpy's [sum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html) that treats NaN as zero by default:

> df['TIE'].str.contains('doneontie', flags=re.I).values.nansum()

3. More on sum that ignore NaN or not:[Pandas sum of two columns - dealing with nan-values correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61636049/12846804)